# Проверка наличия директории через bat файл

Tags: cmd, bat

можете подсказать скрипт который будет проверять есть ли папка AD в директории C:\Users\brsas\Videos\Captures. Если она есть запускать выполнять один код, если нет то создавать там папку AD и выполнять другой код

Answer (score 3):

как-то так:

```
@echo off

IF EXIST "C:\Users\brsas\Videos\Captures\AD" (
    echo directory exists
) ELSE (
    echo Not EXIST 
    mkdir "C:\Users\brsas\Videos\Captures\AD"
    echo directory created
)
```

[аналогичный вопрос на en.so](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21033801/2393786)